How to use tf.data.dataset with xarray
I'm new with data from SQL, when I make my Query I got a xarray.
I try to find how to pass it to tf.data.dataset to buil on power of graph.
I have realy big data to feed to the model so I need to be fast in loading and feeding multi GPU.
All exemple I found use a convertion to a df like pandas to make data transformation and turn it to tf.data.dataset at the end.
ex:
df_xds = xds.data.to_dataframe().reset_index() 
... make modification to data
tf_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(df_xds))

this is my code:

import xdatasets as xd
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import plotly.express as px
import geopandas as gpd
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


path = '/dbfs/mnt/era5-na-cds-grid-single-levels-reanalysis/zarr-timeseries'
ds = xr.open_zarr(path, consolidated=True)


datasets={'era5_single_levels': {'data': ds, 
                           'variables': ['d2m', 't2m', 'tp', 'u10', 'v10', 'ptype']}}

time = {"timestep": "D",
        "aggregation": {"d2m": np.nanmean,
                        "t2m": [np.nanmin, np.nanmax],
                        "tp": np.nansum,
                        "u10": np.nansum,
                        "v10": np.nansum,
                        "ptype": np.nanmean
                        }                       
        }

space = {
        "clip": "polygon", # bbox, point or polygon
        "averaging": False, # spatial average of the variables within each polygon
        "geometry": gdf[gdf['NOM']=='Mekinac'],
        "unique_id": "NOM" # unique column name in geodataframe
    }

xds = xd.Query(datasets=datasets,
              space=space,
            #  time=time,
               )


???
